# Csrf token invalid when the user press the back button and sumbit the login form again - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web, csrf

Problem: The user returns login sucessfully, press back button and send the login details again.

Maybe something that disable login page if you're already logged

Example:

1. I'm the user fill the form and press "Acceder"
   [image]
2. Login Successfully, dashboard view is visible now.

[image]

3. I press the back button in my browser and Log in form appears. I fill the data and send the login details again. I get this error because the user is already logged

[image]

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

If You Can Turn OFF CSRF Token .

You can Disable CSRF on routes.

**App/Http/Kernel.php**:

```
    'web' => [
//            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],
```

Comment: Mmmm but the csrf it's necessary for secure, if we disable the csrf token maybe works fine, but probably with a big secure problem. Thanks for your answer